# Remove <style> tags globally using Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex in JavaScript to remove all `<style>`, `<style type="text/css">`, `</style>`, `<style type="text/css"/>`. The final result would be just the CSS without the style tags.

For some reason the code below doesn't work.

```
str.replace(/<style\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/style)<[^<]*)*<\/style>/gi,'');
```

Comment: What have you tried? any working code at all?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, notice, that you shouldn't use regex for setting the task if you want a regex as a result. Better use human language, for otherwards you can have the error in the task formulation already. It is not your case now, but it happens too often. Otherwards, it is an acceptable question for the first time. +1.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question the following regex code should suffice

```
var regex = /((<style>)|(<style type=.+)|(<\/style>))/g;
var str = `<style>
 styles
</style>

<style type="text/css">
 styles
</style>`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
var result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/OxYINu/2)

---

**Update**

check out the updated regex it removes the styles as well as the content within.

```
var regex = /((<style>)|(<style type=.+))((\s+)|(\S+)|(\r+)|(\n+))(.+)((\s+)|(\S+)|(\r+)|(\n+))(<\/style>)/g;
const str = `<style>
 styles
</style>

<style type="text/css">
 styles
</style>

non html content`;
var subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
var result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/OxYINu/3)

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I'm wondering if it's possible to remove any attributes inside the style tag just in case it contains media or scoped.

Comment: @jsnewbie It does not work, for it takes `<style type="text/css" fghjk$%>>>><<<<>`, too

Comment: @Gangnus the regex was provided in accordance with the OPs question, the question does not state that there will be junk/gibberish values in the tags. See `"How can I use regex in JavaScript to remove all <style>, <style type="text/css">, </style>, <style type="text/css"/>. "`

Comment: @ImmortalDude Exactly. And your regex will match **not only these substrings**

Answer (score 1):

First, correct your regex: use \s+ instead of \b, set correctly the argument after type=, add  tag variant

```
/((<style>)|(<style\s+type=(?:".*"|'.*')\/?)|(<\/style>))/gi
```

Don't forget that there will be two engines that will read your string. Regex engine is the second one. The first one is Javascript. And it demands escaping of `\`, for example.

```
.replace(/((<style>)|(<style\s+type=(?:".*"|'.*')\\/?)|(<\\/style>))/gi,'');
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/Ycg6Ua/3)

Answer (score 0):

To capture inline style you can use

```
style="(.*)"
```

**[Demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Ycg6Ua/2/)**

Comment: Create a noncatching group and add |'(.*)'

Answer (score 0):

Update for remove inline style:

```
.replace(/ style=("[^"]*")|('[^']*')/g, "");
```